# Pass vector of memeber functions to Base class function

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, function-pointers

How can one do this? I need inheritance because there will be a lots of Child classes (and they will differ in "printers" function) but "creator_function" will be same for all of them and Child function inherit more features than this problematic one.

I do not know parts in ??

1. Header of creator_function
2. Calling passed function
3. Passing functions to creator_function

```
    class Base
    {
    public:
        void creator_function(vector< ?(int)functions_p(int)? > printers)
        {
           for(int i; i<printers.size(); i++)
           {
              ?int val = printers[i](10*i);?
              /* create some result here from val of all printers */
           }
        }
    };

    class Child : Base
    {
    public:
        int printer1(int x){ return x; }
        int printer2(int y){ return 2*y; }

        void create_result()
        {
            ? creator_function( {printer1, printer2} ); ?
        }
    };

Child c;
c->create_result();
```

I am lost in pointers to member function that are inhereted.

**printer1 and printer2 "can not" be declared in Base** because there will be lots of different printers in Child classes (with same return type and arguments), but different number of printers and different names in each Child class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to get messy trying to do a method invocation of a child class from a base class.  Remember, pointer to member functions can only be invoked with an instance ("this") of that class.

The classic solution would be to have a separate printer base class with a virtual `print` method on it.  Then have a `printer1` and `printer2` set of derived classes.  That's a lot more typing.

This is a solid case for where a lambda would be very effective.

With some minor adjustments to your code, it gets very easy.  Notice that that we are now passing to `creator_function` a **const** reference to a vector. That enables us to inline the lambdas directly into the function call from the Child class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:

    typedef std::function<int(int)> pfunc;

    void creator_function(const std::vector<pfunc>& printers)
    {
        for (size_t i=0; i < printers.size(); i++)
        {
            int val = printers[i](10 * i);
        }
    }
};

class Child : Base
{
public:
    int printer1(int x) { return x; }
    int printer2(int y) { return 2 * y; }

    void create_result()
    {
        creator_function({
                             [this](int x) {return printer1(x); },
                             [this](int y) {return printer2(y); }
                         });
    }
};

int main()
{
    Child c;
    c.create_result();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for fast answer - it work perfectly. And moreover is general enough for using with some other functions (of some HASA sub-class for example)